# How to create Most Recently Used list in android studio

Tags: java, android

Im new to app building and im building an application which stores a profile and data. i want to add an activity where i can display a list of the most recently viewed profiles. Where do i start???

Answer (score 0):

When viewing profile add timestamp to it. And when displaying profiles sort them by timestamp you created.

Comment: how do i go about doing that. what ive already done is created a database helper class and a database activity list to display the profiles  and everything works perfectly. now i want to create a new activity for the recently used list so how do i add the timestamp to it?

Comment: sorry to be a bother but i'm still awaiting a response.

Comment: add time stamp in your DB. Each time user clicks a profile the timestamp updated in the DB. In activity when you wish to show your most recent. Sort the by date and display x first profiles.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the timestamp when viewing profile, and store it to profiles table in an additional column in your database. Then when you getting the list of profiles just sort them by column timestamp and show in given way.

To access timestamp you can use next code snippet:

```
long timestamp = new Date().getTime();
```

Just call it when opening profile and store received value to the database if the value already exists - just update it.

Comment: sorry to bother but i still need additional info to get this done..as stated im not a pro at all and ive researched alot and the fact that im a noob is hampering me from even understanding how to go forward in doing this.

Comment: What do you want to ask?

Comment: OK.  I want to create a separate activity with the option to view most recently accessed profiles.  Currently i have a database list activity which is using an arraylist and listview to display all the saved profiles with their data. But i just want to add a most recent option to show only recently accessed profile example like your call log. you make a call and it immediately shows the most recent call you made or received. you talked about a timestamp and create a column in the database. i created the column but im stuck there. dont know what to do from this point onwards

Comment: Now when you open (visit) profile just store timestamp value to database.